# String parsing and getting array index from a text string

Tags: java, string, hash

I parse a nested Json file which had nested objects and array and got the result in Map(String, Object). Result that I am able to get:

RoomStays.RoomStay.RoomRates.RoomRate[15].Rates.Rate[0].Base.DecimalPlaces
RoomStays.RoomStay.RoomRates.RoomRate[15].Rates.Rate[0].Base.AmountBeforeTax
RoomStays.RoomStay.RoomRates.RoomRate[15].Rates.Rate[0].EffectiveDate
RoomStays.RoomStay.RoomRates.RoomRate[15].Rates.Rate[0].RateTimeUnit
RoomStays.RoomStay.RoomRates.RoomRate[15].Rates.Rate[1].RateMode
RoomStays.RoomStay.RoomRates.RoomRate[15].Rates.Rate[1].UnitMultiplier
RoomStays.RoomStay.RoomRates.RoomRate[15].Rates.Rate[1].Base.CurrencyCode
RoomStays.RoomStay.RoomRates.RoomRate[15].Rates.Rate[1].Base.DecimalPlaces
RoomStays.RoomStay.RoomRates.RoomRate[15].Rates.Rate[1].Base.AmountBeforeTax
RoomStays.RoomStay.RoomRates.RoomRate[15].Rates.Rate[1].EffectiveDate
RoomStays.RoomStay.RoomRates.RoomRate[15].Rates.Rate[1].RateTimeUnit
RoomStays.RoomStay.RoomRates.RoomRate[15].AvailabilityStatus
RoomStays.RoomStay.RoomRates.RoomRate[15].NumberOfUnits
RoomStays.RoomStay.RoomRates.RoomRate[15].Total.CurrencyCode

I need to know the index number now like 15 is the index of RoomStays.RoomStay.RoomRates.RoomRate. Help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Question is unclear, what is it that you want? I also think this question would benefit from a sample of your JSON and perhaps some of your code for defining the RoomStays structure.

Answer (score 0):

This works assuming your `RoomRate` array doesn't have duplicate rates.  If you pass the `getArrayIndex` function the `RoomRate` array along with the `RoomRate` instance you want the index of, it will return the index.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] RoomRate = new int[3];    
        RoomRate[0] = 5;
        RoomRate[1] = 10;
        RoomRate[2] = 20;

        int index = getArrayIndex(RoomRate, RoomRate[1]);

        System.out.println(index);
    }

    private static int getArrayIndex(int[] RoomRate, int instance) {        
        int index = 0;      
        for (int i = 0; i < RoomRate.length; i++) {         
            if (RoomRate[i] == instance) {
                index = i;
                break;
            }           
        }
        return index;
    }
```

Comment: Since you have provider an answer maybe you can explain the question, since at least two of us don't have any idea what was being asked.